# Quickbook. How to setup item price differently w/ respect to customers?

Tags: quickbooks

I have been using Quickbook 2013. I sell items to various customers.
The price of item vary depending on the customer. For example, I sell item A to customer B at $20, but at $15 to customer C. Whenever I try to make an invoice, I type in the different prices manually (for the same item) and this is so time consuming sometimes especially when dealing with many items and customers. Isn't there a way to make Quickbook memorize all different item prices? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in QuickBooks Premier and Enterprise. It's called "Price Levels"

- http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/core/qb2k12/contentpackage/core/price_levels/intro_pricelevels.html?family=pro